# Azure nodejs connection issue to mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, azure, azure-web-app-service

We have an issue intermittently connecting to mongodb using the nodejs driver.

This is not a production instance (of mongo) (single machine host as IAAS in azure)

The website has two instances and we have a production and staging slot. That's 4 web applications attempting to connect.

When the issue occurs on a web application, the other 3 can connect normally, even restarting the processes, the other 3 can connect fine, but remains on the failed instance.

This appears not the be an infrastructure/PAAS thing as the either a staging or production slot on the same instance can connect.

I know I can expect this from time-to-time, but the issue is rather sticky once it occurs.

The application exception is:

Mon Jun 27 2016 03:27:37 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time): Application has thrown an uncaught exception and is terminated:

Error: failed to connect to [[ipaddress]:27017]

[stacktrace]

I know this is falling back to iisnode as the message beginning the log is from iisnode source code:
https://github.com/tjanczuk/iisnode/blob/95b5abb29b122beced7af2a2a304c3a4d86f6536/src/scripts/interceptor.js#L201

Just wondering why the process.exit(1) does not return ? or if there is a way to know why this is happening.

Let me know if you can help.

Comment: Have you checked the connection pool of your mongodb server? Will it be the connection limit issue?

Comment: @GaryLiu-MSFT running serverStatus i can see that I have 26/793 connections used. will look more into that. is there a more authoritative way of investigating connection limits?

Comment: @Hoffmania, Could you please share your error message with us for further support? About how to view the error message, please refer to this document(https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-enable-diagnostic-log/)

Comment: @WillShao-MSFT updated the details to include part of the exception details. It's not really the error, just why IISnode does not kick the process. and if we can find out why.

Comment: @Hoffmania, I recommend you could try to click into 'https://[yoursite].scm.azurewebsites.net/ProcessExplorer/' and using KUDU power shell command to start your application and monitor the processor information. Also could you please share the web app's info with us via leveraging the approach that pointed out at https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Reporting-your-site-name-without-posting-it-publicly?

Comment: @WillShao-MSFT I created a webapp thanksforyourhelp in the same service plan. there is only 1 other site in the plan. we see this on the both staging and production slots. Just tried then unfortunately we do not have the issue on the app at the moment. would have been perfect

Comment: @WillShao-MSFT does running the site simulate the same issue or do you just want to show the pid terminating on error? I have been using process monitor for this problem to kick the pid. All of the tools are super helpful once you need to find them :)